# How do I change my Azure function deployment publish configuration from release to debug?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I have created an Azure function app and a function called "Stripe" for listening for Stripe webhooks. I've installed all Azure extensions in VS Code and in the workspace dropdown I can click on deploy and it deploys and runs in Azure. I can connect to the url and all is ok!

But, when I click on "Deploy to func app" here
[image]

I notice that the deployment always builds/publishes with --configuration "Release"
[image]

**QUESTION** - How do I change the configuration from Release to debug either in some config file or from the cli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As of now, Visual Studio Code doesn't support Azure Functions remote debugging**.

Remote debugging is possible from the specific versions of Visual Studio - Azure Functions:
[image: VSRemotedebugging]

There is a [Visual Studio Code limitation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_remote-debugging) on remote debugging, and currently the Remote Debugging is supported only in [Node JS Azure App Service through VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/azure/remote-debugging).

I would suggest raising a ticket in GitHub of [VS Code Request features](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues?q=is:open%20is:issue%20label:feature-request%20sort:reactions-%2b1-desc) and [VS Code Report Issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues) will provide the quick & better resolution from VS Code Official Support.

Comment: ok fair enough, what I'd like to do is set up a function that will work alongside my production function, but point to my dev database. Can this be done without creating a different function? I'm doing this with my app-service-plan (website) using 2 app-services ex. mysite.azurewebsites.net and mysite-dev.azurewebsites.net these are both the same website, but have different connection strings pointing to different db's. One is for production, the other is for dev/testing and based on how building/publishing works using debug as my configuration option will point to the debug connection strings

Comment: I understand that you have one function app pointing to 2 different db's (1 is prod db and other is dev/test db). So, you want to test in the same function that points to particular db while you're testing it, but you don't want to create another function app for another db! Is it correct?

Comment: Maybe, I think I might have butchered my explanation above. Let me try again. I created a function to accept Stripe webhooks. So my 1 function is a HTTP trigger that has the code to read the webhook data and do some stuff. Now, Stripe has provided me with two endpoint url's (prod, dev). Currently, I can deploy my "Stripe" function to Azure and that will use whatever connection string I set plus the Stripe endpoint (prod) used as the function url, but in addition to this, cont....

Comment: I want to deploy the same function but have it use different connection strings and a different function url with a different Stripe endpoint (dev). Can this be done with just 1 function or do I have to create a whole new function? It seems like I have to create a whole new function, but that makes me have to write the function twice or copy and paste the code into the second function, making the code all redundant. Or have a separate file that both the functions end up calling, so 99% of the code for the function will reside in a different file. That doesn't sound good con't...

Comment: Ex. One single function called "Stripe" with multiple function URL's (Ex. Stripe-prod.azurewebsites.net, Stripe-dev.azurewebsites.net) and that have different connection strings to my prod and dev db, but it is just a single (1) function in VS Code. I'm looking at slots, but that seems like it's nmore for staging, before you push to prod, but not sure if it's meant for different connections strings and url's

Comment: Yes, it is possible! You can create the deployment slots in Azure Function App Portal > Prod Slot, Staging/dev/testing slot > After that, you can deploy testing conn string function to the staging slot

Comment: But the important thing is I need to have staging and prod slots to have different function urls (ex. function1-prod.azurewebsites.net, function1-dev.azurewebsites.net) because Stripe has a dev/test env. and a prod. environment and both env's have different urls

Comment: Azure Function App Portal will differentiate the URLs when you deployed the same function to different slots. For example, see this [image](https://i.imgur.com/QXoWRjw.png). So, you can easily identify the function based on its URL either prod or staging.

Comment: ah I see! I'm not familiar with slots yet, if I push to a slot (ex. dev slot) does that mean at some point I have to go from the dev slot into the production slot, or can I just use the dev slot as a playground?

Comment: You can use the dev slot as a playground for complete testing purpose until your functionality is working correctly. Later you can push/deploy to the production slot if all the functionality requirements are met.